# Matlab passing data to another GUI

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

I am new to Matlab, kindly guide me on this question.
I have two figures, I would like to pass data from first figure to second figure.
Code:

```
function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
    tryText=get(handles.text2,'String');
    open SecondPage.fig
guidata(hObject,handles);
```

how do I pass the data in "tryText" and use it in second figure?

I tried passing the data using this format:

```
function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
    tryText=get(handles.text2,'String');
    SecondPage(tryText)
guidata(hObject,handles);
```

but I have no luck retrieving it.
Thanks

Latest Update:

```
function varargout = first(varargin)
handles=struct;
datas=struct;
    gui_Singleton = 1;
    gui_State = struct('gui_Name',       mfilename, ...
                       'gui_Singleton',  gui_Singleton, ...
                       'gui_OpeningFcn', @first_OpeningFcn, ...
                       'gui_OutputFcn',  @first_OutputFcn, ...
                       'gui_LayoutFcn',  [] , ...
                       'gui_Callback',   []);
    if nargin && ischar(varargin{1})
        gui_State.gui_Callback = str2func(varargin{1});
    end

    if nargout
        [varargout{1:nargout}] = gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
    else
        gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
    end

function first_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)
     handles.output = hObject;
guidata(hObject, handles);

function varargout = first_OutputFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles) 

varargout{1} = handles.output;

function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
    struct.a=get(handles.edit1,'String');
        set(handles.text1,'String',struct.a);
        disp(struct);
    setappdata(0,'MyStruct',struct);
open second.fig
```

Mean while in Second:

```
function varargout = second(varargin)
    getappdata(0,'MyStruct');
        gui_Singleton = 1;
        gui_State = struct('gui_Name',       mfilename, ...
                       'gui_Singleton',  gui_Singleton, ...
                       'gui_OpeningFcn', @second_OpeningFcn, ...
                       'gui_OutputFcn',  @second_OutputFcn, ...
                       'gui_LayoutFcn',  [] , ...
                       'gui_Callback',   []);
    if nargin && ischar(varargin{1})
        gui_State.gui_Callback = str2func(varargin{1});
    end

    if nargout
        [varargout{1:nargout}] = gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
    else
        gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
    end


function second_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)
    handles.output = hObject;
guidata(hObject, handles);

function varargout = second_OutputFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles) 

varargout{1} = handles.output;


function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
disp(struct)
```

in first figure, the result of disp(struct) is correct, while in second figure, it shows "1x1 struct array with no fields."
Can someone highlight where is my mistake? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use handles and data structures to do that. Instead of showing you how to do it here, I will simply point you to [an answer given in MATLAB Central](http://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/49886-passing-data-between-diferent-guis) which tells you exactly how you can achieve this.

Comment: Dear ha9u63ar, thanks for your reply, i have checked it, yet I can't manage to retrieve the data in my second figure, I have uploaded the code, do you mind telling where is my mistake? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply, I finally manage to make it work with the following code.

Code:

```
  function varargout = second(varargin)

    gui_Singleton = 1;
    gui_State = struct('gui_Name',       mfilename, ...
                   'gui_Singleton',  gui_Singleton, ...
                   'gui_OpeningFcn', @second_OpeningFcn, ...
                   'gui_OutputFcn',  @second_OutputFcn, ...
                   'gui_LayoutFcn',  [] , ...
                   'gui_Callback',   []);
    if nargin && ischar(varargin{1})
        gui_State.gui_Callback = str2func(varargin{1});
    end

    if nargout
        [varargout{1:nargout}] = gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
    else
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
    end


function second_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)
    handles.output = hObject;
guidata(hObject, handles);

function varargout = second_OutputFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles) 

varargout{1} = handles.output;


function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
    struct=getappdata(0,'MyStruct');
disp(struct)
```